# Is there a way to get a list of all the fields in a mainframe system (IBM Pcomm) using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, automation, mainframe, ibm-pcomm

While trying to use the autECLFieldList method in C#, "//using AutECLFieldList;", the compiler shows the error that reference is not added. Also, is there a way wherein we can use a loop to get a list of the field elements and their contents by using AutECLFieldList.gettext or something similar.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the actual error message ?